# How do I increase the size of a token.File?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a rewriter that uses `go/ast` to add some things to a file.  Everything is working well, except for the comments, which `go/ast` is notoriously awful at.  But part of the problem seems to be that it's actively conspiring against my efforts to fix it.

I have an insertion near the end of the file that is larger than what was left in the file.  There are a couple other `func`s after that point, and they have comments on them.  I used a visitor to calculate the appropriate `Pos` for my update and then update the remaining nodes with a new `Pos` so that they wouldn't lose their association with their comments, but now the comments are getting moved to *above* my insertion!

After tracing through the execution, what I found is that `func (s *FileSet) PositionFor` in `position.go` is returning 0 on the position of those remaining comments, because their new `Pos` is beyond the end of the associated `token.File` data.  Well, then it looks like I need to update the `size` on that `token.File`, but it's a lower-case field so I can't do that directly, and there doesn't appear to be any method that will do it for me.  `size` appears to be immutable, only set at construction time, which is odd because other parts of the `token.File` structs can be updated.

How in the world do I resolve this?  I just want my comments to print where they're supposed to be, but every time I think I've fixed the problem, there's some other problem lurking behind it, and now I run into an immutable problem!

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @icza That would be difficult, as there's a large amount of code involved here, scattered over several files, and even reducing it down to something simple would still involve a lot of code